# How to increase the tableview cell height based on label height if there is a view on content view of the cell Swift 3?

Tags: iphone, swift3, ios10

I want to increase the tableview cell height based on the label height.I know that after iOS8 apple has made developers life easier to achieve this thing by setting the following things.

```
self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 88.0
self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
}
```

So,to give the cells better look and shape, I have placed a custom view on tableview cell's content view, and label (whose content will change dynamically based on the web service response) on my custom view , so that i can make the view look better.

I have set 4 constraints (Leading, trailing, top, & bottom) for View with respect to content view as well as for label with respect to my custom view and i have also set number of lines for label as 0.

Since there is a custom view in between content view and label, i want to increase the view height based on the height of the label.

My question is how can i get the label's height and increase the view height so that i can show all the content in the label.

Early suggestions would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

How about the delegate function?

```
  - (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)aTableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
   switch (indexPath.row){
       case 0:
         if(indexPath.section==0)
            return 88.0; // your particular row
       default:
         return 40.0; // all other rows  
   }
}
```